# Cron job: problem with crontab, it automatically sending me an email

Tags: cron

How can I disable the email on the cron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the output to `/dev/null` like this:

```
* * * * * my_command > /dev/null
```

If an error occurs, you'll still get an email, though.

Answer (score 2):

Send the standard output (and standard error) of your cron job to `/dev/null`

```
* * * * *  /some/cron/job 1> /dev/null 2>&1
```

If you'd prefer a log file, change `/dev/null` to a real filename instead, but be aware of the security issues.  Specifically, if you're running with any sort of privileged account and the log file doesn't already exist, a hacker can pre-create a symlink in place of your log file, pointing at some other file.  When your cron job runs the target of the symlink gets overwritten.